# How can I have a Time field in Dynamics CRM 4.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm

I know nothing about CRM but have been asked to add some fields to a form. One of these is for a time but with no date element. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

CRM does not provide this functionality out of the box.  You'll need to customize it.  I'd add a new DateTime attribute and a new Text attribute.  capture the data you need in the DateTime attribute so you can report off of it.  Then using Javascript, display only the time portion from the DateTime attribute in the Text field.

-Mikeyb

Answer (score 0):

I would add a datetime field with a format of date and time. On form load, you can add javascript to populate the date part with a constant value then hide it so that it only shows the time part.