# Hide the date part on a DateTime field

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I would like to have a time-only field on my CRM form. As it is [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720994/how-can-i-have-a-time-field-in-dynamics-crm-4-0) not possible, I plan to use a DateTime field and hide the date part (circled in red on the following image).

[image]

How can I hide the date part on a DateTime field using Javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
// Set the date in order to be able to modify the time
document.getElementById("field_name").DataValue = new Date(2000, 1, 1);
// Hide the date part
document.getElementById("field_name").childNodes[0].childNodes[0].style.display =
    "none";
document.getElementById("field_name").childNodes[0].childNodes[1].style.display =
    "none";
```

Comment: This no longer works in the newer versions of Dynamics CRM and Dynamics 365.